# Plone i18n - how much from each Language

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I am looking for the table of Plone last version i18n
 how much is translated from each Language?

Answer (score 6):

How to check this:

- pip install i18ndude
- Create a checkout of https://github.com/collective/plone.app.locales
- Change directory to `plone.app.locales/plone/app/locales/locales`
- Run the command `i18ndude list -p plone`

Result today (2 May 2016):

```
Messages: 2688

Tier 1:

100% - English (en)
 93% - French (fr)
 92% - Italian (it)
 73% - German (de)
 89% - Spanish (es)
 74% - Dutch (nl)
  0% - Chinese (China) (zh-cn)
 94% - Chinese (Taiwan) (zh-tw)
 80% - Japanese (ja)
 10% - Korean (ko)
 94% - Portuguese (Brazil) (pt-br)
 78% - Russian (ru)
 58% - Polish (pl)
 52% - Turkish (tr)
 13% - Thai (th)
 39% - Arabic (ar)

Tier 2:

  0% - Swedish (sv)
 58% - Finnish (fi)
 87% - Danish (da)
 49% - Portuguese (pt)
 61% - Romanian (ro)
 37% - Hungarian (hu)
 41% - Hebrew (he)
 42% - Indonesian (id)
 70% - Czech (cs)
 28% - Greek (el)
 53% - Norwegian (no)
 47% - Vietnamese (vi)
 47% - Bulgarian (bg)
  9% - Croatian (hr)
 37% - Lithuanian (lt)
 54% - Slovak (sk)
  0% - Tagalog (tl)
 82% - Slovenian (sl)
 22% - Serbian (sr)
 63% - Catalan (ca)
 30% - Latvian (lv)
 87% - Ukrainian (uk)
  7% - Hindi (hi)

Tier 3:

 55% - Afrikaans (af)
  3% - Albanian (sq)
  9% - Armenian (hy)
100% - Basque (eu)
  8% - Bengali (bn)
 18% - Burmese (my)
 16% - Chinese (Hongkong) (zh-hk)
 73% - Chinese Simplified (zh_CN)
 53% - Esperanto (eo)
 18% - Estonian (et)
 17% - Furlan (fu)
 39% - Galician (gl)
 16% - Georgian (ka)
 15% - Kannada (kn)
 22% - Macedonian (mk)
  9% - Nynorsk (nn)
 18% - Persian (fa)
  8% - Tamil (ta)
  8% - Telugu (te)
 18% - Welsh (cy)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Look](https://github.com/collective/plone.app.locales/) at plone.app.locales, you can find the core-translations in this package.